# Doctrine2: proper organisation of CRUD operations.

Tags: php, model, doctrine-orm, crud

Need some advice on how to organise CRUD operations for model using doctrine2. 
I use yaml mapping file for table definition. Auto generate model classes, proxies and custom repository classes. In my entity repository classes i define methods for complex SQl, DQL. But i'm not sure where i must put Create, Update and Delete operations? In repository class? In model class?

Comment: **Good question!** I ran into the same issue recently and found nothing informative. Everybody states to use the entityManager, but nothing about where to put operations or how to organize related files. **My approach:** Use `App\Entity` for your entity-classes, `App\Repository` for entity related getter-/find-methods and `App\EntityDataHandler` for CRUD related operations. An EntityDataHandler has methods like `updateData` or `removeEntityById`, for instance. I also would name it like the related entity, like `App\Entity\Foo` => `App\EntityDataHandler\FooDataHandler`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you only work with the entity manager, say from a controller, and the `em` then handles all the actual CRUD operations. There shouldnt really be a reason for custom methods for this, unless you want to run some kind of mass update on something or other. In that case it would go in the repository class as opposed to the entity.